How to hide/restrict past date in DatePicker in SwiftUI?
I have implemented Datepicker, and restricted user to select past date. User can able to scroll to past date but it automatically auto scroll to current date. But I want to completely hide the past dates or restrict user to scroll to past date.
    var dateRange: ClosedRange<Date> {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let endComponents = DateComponents(year: 2100)
        let startDate = Date.now
        let endDate = calendar.date(from: endComponents) ?? Date.now
        let rangeStart = minimumDate ?? startDate
        return rangeStart...endDate
    }

  HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        DatePicker("", selection: $pickerDate, in: dateRange, displayedComponents: .date)
                            .tint(wedding?.weddingThemeForegroundColor() ?? HHColor.primarydarkblue)
                            .datePickerStyle(.graphical)
                            .id(pickerDate)
                            .fontWithLineHeight(font: UIFont(name: HHFonts.Lato_Bold.rawValue, size: 46), lineHeight: 24)
                            .padding(.bottom, 12)
                            .padding(.leading, 16)
                            .padding(.trailing, 40)
                        Spacer()
                    }


Unrelated but rather than having what I assume is an arbitrary end date you can use an open range with the picker, range start…

You can't using SwiftUI. If you want to hide them you need to create a custom view or use the UIKit Picker
